# TVS Jupiter starting trouble

Tags: starting, scooter, tvs-jupiter

I had bought TVS Jupiter 4 years back (2014). It was good until last year.

The big problem I am facing now is morning start if I do not start scooter even for one day, the next day I will have to spend 15 min kicking to get it started.
Initially, I thought it was a battery issue, replaced the battery with a new one.
then took to service center he said he has fixed it and gave it back saying carburetor issue.

I continue to face the same issue, when I took it again to the same service provider, he just checked the smoke and told some oil leakage is causing this issue from the engine valve, it requires INR 3500 or around $ 51, he did not check anything else.

I'm not sure if he is trying to fool me or not. Surprisingly once it gets started it works like butter, next time it will start in half kick also. If its a problem with leakage it should give problem always, why only on the first start? My doubt is even if I spend this much, I can not verify if the problem is fixed until I take it home and leave it for 1-2 days.

Need some expert comment!

Comment: HI Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair

Comment: Have you checked the spark plug?What was the last time you had replaced it?

Comment: yes, even i was thinking, why mechanic did not check it. can spark plug give this kind of issue as it happens only in first start.

Comment: yes it would cause issues if it has deposits and if no proper gap

Comment: Pls sell it off.. Everyone facing same issue..i have 2 jupiter in my family...all have same issue...no fix from jupiter service center.